Is there a practical difference between useReducer and useState with a callback?
Let's say we had a basic reducer function like this:
function reducer(state, action) {
    if(action.type === 'add')
        return state + action.value;
    if(action.type === 'multiply')
        return state * action.value;
    return state;
}

Is there a practical difference between using our reducer with useReducer:
const [x, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, 1);
dispatch({ type: 'add', value: 2 });
dispatch({ type: 'multiply', value: 10 });

Or using our reducer with useState:
const [x, setX] = useState(1);
setX(x => reducer(x, { type: 'add', value: 2 }));
setX(x => reducer(x, { type: 'multiply', value: 10 }));

What I'm asking is whether or not there is a fundamental difference between how react handles these examples or if useReducer is really just useState with syntactic sugar.

You’re correct, it’s basically entirely syntactic sugar. There’s no performance difference or anything else to be concerned about. Write the code in the way that’s clearest to you and your team. I don’t think I ever personally used useReducer because I think it semi-encourages large complex state (which results in large complex code). But that’s just me and my opinion.

One practical difference would be managing large amounts of state. Once a component has many different pieces of state being managed, there's a good chance that you're calling setState multiple times in a row inside of different functions. If that is the case then there is a good opportunity to abstract away all those different state setters into a reducer that can act more like a state machine, updating state due to events.
Basically a reducer scales better than useState

The "practical difference" is code readability and maintainability.
How React handles useState and useReducer is indeed very similar, you could almost say identical (currently).
Generally in React, which should be seen as a high level abstraction, you should just follow the rules and recommendations, and don't ask for the implementation details. You might even willingly sacrifice some performance for cleaner code (in non-performance-critical situations).
I.e. two React mechanisms might work exactly the same or totally different, but that doesn't matter, you are using React to write declarative code and commonly known patterns, and let React handle the implementation.
E.g. imagine useState or useReducer might be implemented in some way today, but tomorrow they change one of them fundamentally because they noticed they can optimize something significantly under the assumption that people mostly follow the recommendations. But the usage of both of them would stay the same, and you don't have to care, React simply became a little bit faster as far as you are concerned.
But of course, it is good to be curious:
Your assumption is correct, useState and useReducer do almost the same. As far as I know (not 100% sure), useState is (or was) even using useReducer internally. That means useState would be syntactic sugar of useReducer, not the other way around.
Regarding performance:
Of course, one function declaration and/or function call more or less, as in your example, should theoretically make a difference regarding performance, but that should be negligible, or even not true in practice (due to compiler optimizations maybe. I don't know). But that's probably not the point of your question.
See also: Comparing useState and useReducer

While there are differences between the two, they're mostly regarding how these two handle complex logic and performance. At the very core, however, they complete the same task.
We can examine this closer:
useReducer would be more beneficial to use for with a more complex state logic as it prevents the action of unnecessary re-renders. We can see this in the example you provided as the reducer function has been clearly separated away from its component, thus showing that the component is not responsible for updates regarding state logic.
useState, on the other hand, manually calls the reducer function and is also responsible for updates regarding state logic. This, despite being functional, can quickly begin to struggle with performance once the state logic becomes more complex.

Can you explain in more detail which specific differences there are between the two approaches regarding re-renders and performance ?
